# Merge Columns from CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

I've got a CSV like this:

```
Group;Name;Color
Fruit;Apple;green
Vegetable;Carrot;orange
Fruit;Banana;yellow
Fruit;cherry;red
Vegetable;cucumber;green
```

and want to merge it (via PowerShell) so that each Group appears only one time and the according 'Names' next to it in an Array(?), like this:

```
Group;Name;color
Fruit;{Apple,Banana,Cherry};{green,yellow,red}
Vegetable;{Carrot;cucumber};{orange,green}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Group-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849907.aspx) for grouping objects by their properties:

```psh
Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\input.csv' -Delimiter ';' |
  Group-Object Group |
  select @{n='Group';e={$_.Name}},
         @{n='Name';e={'{{{0}}}' -f ($_.Group.Name -join ',')}},
         @{n='Color';e={'{{{0}}}' -f ($_.Group.Color -join ',')}} |
  Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -NoType -Delimiter ';'
```